# Is mindfulness itself kamma ? does it create kamma?

Tags: karma, mindfulness

Is mindfulness itself kamma ? does it create kamma ? is it one of the 50 types of kamma ?

(my teacher who is a monk told me mindfulness is kamma  - and like kamma its an accumulated thing )

Im asking cause if mindfulness is kamma than its accumlated - and if its accumlated it answers my "problem"  :

[Is there a value for a single moment of mindfulness (without others) ?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/is-there-a-value-for-a-single-moment-of-mindfulness-without-others)

Answer (score 2):

[Fabrication (Sankhara)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%85kh%C4%81ra), consists of 50 of the [52 Mental Factors (cetasika)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_factors_(Buddhism)). [Mindfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(Buddhism)) appears in the 25 mental factors which arise with wholesome consciousness. Mindfulness is wholesome as it aids liberation. Unlike some factors which accumulates Fabrication which is one which aids in not creating new fabrication which keeps a being in misery. Also what every is Wholesome is not necessary accumulation of positive Karmic Fabrications. The reduction in accumulated Karma is also Wholesome are you are more closer to liberation. Also note the 50 cetasikas are not all wholesome and they influence karmic accumulation.

Comment: Sorry i dont do resarch before i ask i want to get as much detailed answers as i can  - im trying to determine whtere being mindful is an accumulated thing like kamma is 

My meditation teacher who is a monk said to me midfulness is kamma - is he wrong ? 


If somehow i am sure mindfulness is kamma it will help me solving this "problem"  :

http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/is-there-a-value-for-a-single-moment-of-mindfulness-without-others

Comment: cetasika  are kammas ?  Saṅkhāra are kamma ?

Comment: Kusala Karma is made by the reduction of accumulating fabrications. It is Kusala because the result is conducive. In many cases Karma = Fabrication but not always.

Comment: so are you saying mindfulness is not karma but can clear karma ? or is it karma itslef ?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

There are two types of karma , positive karma and negative karma.
Karma are acts done by body ,words and mind.
Mindfulness itself is not a karma since  it is not an act.
But it will reduce the negative karma that  you'd do unknowingly.because you are aware of your mind.
Thus eventually it will help you to achieve nirvana even though doesn't create karma.

Comment: What about the answer below saying that mindfulness sati is part of the 52 mental factors  (cetasika)  -  are this factors not karma ? or Saṅkhāra not kamma ?

Comment: I really don't know about that , I just tried to help with what I know :-)

Comment: OK - so will say it different :   kamma isnt intention though ? being mindful isnt an act of being mindful ?

Comment: Kamma is acts done with intention. Being mindful is just being aware of your mind and acts, it can not be considered as an act done by mind because if it is an act you have to be mindful about being mindful,

Comment: in 1 minute medtation what good kamma is made ?

Comment: Mindfulness is not awareness of the mind. Mindfulness means to remember to apply dhamma principles.

Answer (score 1):

Right mindfulness is an intentional (mental) act therefore it is kamma. However it falls under a 3rd type of kamma that is called the "kamma that ends kamma".

AN 6.63 states the noble eightfold path is the kamma that ends kamma therefore right mindfulness falls within this.

Comment: Dhammadhatu can you re answer my question about the value of a single moment of mindfulness -    but with taking in mind this question  

and if you cant give 2 answers you can delete the old one you gave

Comment: Cause if a single moment of mindfulness is kamma  - and it ends kamma - than it has value it is "accumelative"  in a sense  that it has its effect even if its just a single moment of mindfulness right ?  

meaning even if i am mindful 1 moment this life time  - it has a point right ?

Comment: Good & bad kamma (action) & good & bad results are based in self-view. Where as the 3rd type of kamma is based on the ending of self-view. When there is Right Mindfulness, nothing is clung to as being "I", "me", "mine" and "myself". This is why the 3rd type of kamma ends kamma. Right mindfulness only happens when the mind is not thinking in terms of "I".

Comment: yes of course there is (itching,tiered,rising,falling ect) im aware of the basics -  but for conventional terms i use this language  and i would like to understand the value of a single moment of mindfulness without connection to others