# Does mindfulness end kamma ? is that a good thing ?

Tags: karma, mindfulness

Does mindfulness end kamma ? is that a good thing ?

!!! yes I am aware that the goal is not to attach to anything so avoiding suffering and that good kamma in the end is also "bad"  !!!

I am asking about whats the benifits of mindfulness eradicating kamma becaus :

Dont we all have a ton of kamma from a gigantic amount of kamma and if we eradicate kammas throw mindfulness it will just be replaced with other kammas which can also be bad kammas ?

i mean its not like we reach nibana by cleaning up all the kamma "We" got - but by developing wisdom  so whats the good thing about mindfulness ending *spesific* (not all)  kammas ?

I ask this after receiving this reply (and wanted this as a follow up different question) :

"Right mindfulness is an intentional (mental) act therefore it is kamma. However it falls under a 3rd type of kamma that is called the "kamma that ends kamma". "

from here (I wanted this as a follow up in different new question) :

[Is mindfulness itself kamma ? does it create kamma?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18689/is-mindfulness-itself-kamma-does-it-create-kamma)

Answer (score 1):

What is wholesome is what you perceive positively at the time the result manifests. Since all worldly experiences are unsatisfactory, experiencing Nirvana is wholesome. Anything that reduces your stress and suffering is a good thing.

When you are practice Right Mindfulness, you do not create new Karma then your old Karmas start surfacing which reduce your old stock of karma and newly created karma. Development of the path factors is good Karma. Path factors are also part of the [Mental Factors (cetasika)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_factors_(Buddhism)).

Answer (score 0):

> Does mindfulness end kamma ? is that a good thing ?

It's a necessary condition toward the ending of kamma. But it's not a sufficient condition. SammaSati is one factor to be cultivated among the 8 factors of the [Noble Eightfold Path](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html). Regarding the other question, one even needs to have wholesome desires in order to put an end to all desires. See Ven. Ananda's "park" simile in SN [51.15](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn51/sn51.015.than.html)

Comment: do you have time for a chat ?

Comment: if not - do you think there is value in doing 1 minute of medtation only in 1 year ?   (of course the more the better but asking if its alone does it have value)

Answer (score 0):

**Answering your Question "Is mindfulness itself kamma ? does it create kamma?"**

In short answer Yes mindfulness itself generating Kamma.

1. We need to clarify the word "Kamma" and
2. How it affects to the life?  and
3. How the Kamma nullify in which stages?

Let's do it one by one

**01. We need to clarify the word "Kamma"**

Very simple we can say actions conducting by

- Words using mouth - Verbal deed (vaci-kamma)
- activities using body - Bodily deed (kaya-kamma)
- thoughts using consciousness - Mental deed (mano-kamma)

Further Reading: [Know more about Wholesome Unwholesome acts](https://drarisworld.wordpress.com/2020/04/27/ten-unwholesome-deeds-dasa-akusal-in-theravada-buddhism/)

We have 6 Consciousness born places called

- Chakku[Eye]
- Sotha[Eyers]
- Ghana[Nose]
- Jivha[Tongue]
- Kaya[Body]
- Mana[Consciousness]

We have already inherited those due to our previous Kamma. We called them Purana Kamma[Ancient Kamma]. Now Leading consciousness we are doing actions by using word body, and mind.

Example:
When a mosquito bite. First you feel Vedana[Pain]. Then suddenly your hand works and hit the mosquito. But that hand works due to your pain consciousness act and hand works. Now you completed a bad kamma.  At the same time when the hand works consciousness suddenly think that killing is a sin i should not conduct that evil act and instead killing you simply make mosquito fly. Then you avoid killing and you did the wholesome act means good Kamma.

Likewise whole our life is filled with thoughts and actions and we are in the process of continuous kamma generating.  In a eye blink like this millions trillions thoughts are processing and each has it's own Kamma processing 7 thought we called them "Javana" which generates the future results of that action.

Similarly, while you are engaging in mindfulness, what you are doing is controlling your sensory organs engaging in unwholesome acts and instead engage them in wholesome acts. So all thoughts that you are processing in that moment 7 Javan consciousnesses resulting you the future Good Kamma.

**02. How it affects to the life?  and**
To have better understand of the Javana read this; [Seven Javana](http://meditationmyanmar.blogspot.com/2011/10/seven-javana.html)

Once you read above webpage you will have the better understanding of the Javana and how it affects the life and how it's nullified.

**1. Stream Enterer**

The first stage is that of Sotāpanna (Pali; Sanskrit: Srotāpanna), literally meaning “one who enters (āpadyate) the stream (sotas),” with the stream being the Noble Eightfold Path regarded as the highest Dharma.

The stream-enterer is also said to have “opened the eye of the Dharma” and is guaranteed enlightenment after no more than seven successive rebirths, possibly fewer.

**2. Once Returner**

The second stage is that of the Sakadāgāmī (Sanskrit: Sakṛdāgāmin), literally meaning “one who once (sakṛt) comes (āgacchati)”. The once-returner will return to the human world only one more time, and will attain Nirvana in that life.

**3. Never Returner**

The third stage is that of the Anāgāmī (Sanskrit: Anāgāmin), literally meaning “one who does not (an-) come (āgacchati)”. The non-returner does not come back into human existence, or any lower world, after death. Instead, he is reborn in one of the worlds of the Rūpadhātu called the Śuddhāvāsa worlds, or “Pure Abodes”, where he will attain Nirvāṇa; Pāli: Nibbana; some of them are reborn a second time in a higher world of the Pure Abodes, but in no case are born into a lower state.

**4. Arahant**

The fourth stage is that of Arahant, a fully enlightened human being who has abandoned all fetters, and who upon decease (Sanskrit: Parinirvāṇa, Pāli: Parinibbāna) will not be reborn in any world, having wholly abandoned saṃsāra.

There are 5 Main Unwholesome acts which resulting even in Arhants.
Those are:

1. Killing Mother
2. Killing Father
3. Killing Arahanth
4. Shaking Lord Buddha's Body Blood
5. Arranging the sangha to fight each other [this happen in between Sangha only]

May you be able to find the way to attain Nibbana!!! May Triple Gem Bless you!!!